# Add to table only 10 values

Tags: lua

How i can add to table only max 10 users ?
Because i saving scoretbl in txt, and this file have more 100 lines :/ So i want save only 10 users.

I don't know how can i check there is username in the table, and don't add this user or not this username in the table and add it?

Example:

```
local scoretbl = {}
local num = 0
for i=1, 10 do
    table.insert(scoretbl,{'Name '..i, 100 + num})
    num = num + 100
end

local function AddToTable(name, score)
    if table.HasValue(scoretbl,name) then return end // hmm its not work ?
        table.insert(scoretbl,{name, score})
end

AddToTable('User 55', 5454)// 11 user
AddToTable('User 55', 5454)// check: only one username in table

AddToTable('User 32', 5454)// 12 user

local function ShowOnly10()
table.sort( scoretbl, function( a, b ) return a[2] > b[2] end )

//table.remove(scoretbl,#scoretbl) remove last index in table, if i need only 10 value, i need delete in cycle ?

    for k, v in pairs(scoretbl) do
        print(k ,v[1], v[2])
    end
end
ShowOnly10()
```

// upd: maybe its fix username ?

```
local function AddToTable(name, score)
    for k, v in pairs(scoretbl) do
        if v[1] == name then return false end
    end
    table.insert(scoretbl,{name, score}) 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you make use of Lua's hashtable, `v.name` and `v.score` are easier to read than `v[1]` and `v[2]`.

The function `table.HasValue` does not exist.  You have to write your own.

When you want to print only the first ten elements, you should only iterate over the first ten (or up to the length of the table if it is less than ten elements long).

Line comments in Lua start with `--`, not `//`.

```
local scoretbl = {}

for i = 1,10 do
    table.insert(scoretbl, { name = 'Name '..i, score = 100*i })
end

local function AddToTable(name, score)
    -- Walk the whole table to find whether a name exists
    for i,v in ipairs(scoretbl) do
        if v.name == name then
            -- if the record is present, update it
            scoretbl[i].score = score
            return
        end
    end
    -- Insert new record
    table.insert(scoretbl, { name = name, score = score })
end

AddToTable('User 55', 5454) -- 11 users
AddToTable('User 55', 5454) -- check: only one username in table
AddToTable('User 32', 5454) -- 12 users

local function ShowOnly10()
    table.sort(scoretbl,function(a,b) return a.score > b.score end)

    for i = 1,math.min(#scoretbl,10) do
        print(i, scoretbl[i].name, scoretbl[i].score)
    end
end

ShowOnly10()
```

Comment: If value changed from user, that not change in table ?
See this: https://i.imgur.com/lJpXv7k.png
I modified on this: https://i.imgur.com/w65go4G.png

Comment: @Gigabait The code in the updated answer will update existing records.